# DOM manipulation even handlers

Tags: javascript, dom, web

I want to add an Event handler to this button I created with an event handler.  I don't know how to tell this button to go to a function MarkCell() when clicked though.  I know that I will use the onClick Event but I don't know how to tell it what onClick event.  I have to use DOM manipulation.

```
var right = document.createElement("Button");
var t = document.createTextNode("RIGHT");
right.appendChild(t);
document.body.appendChild(right);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the addEventListener method to attach an event handler. For example...

```
function markCell() {
    console.log("markCell called.");
}

var right = document.createElement("Button");
var t = document.createTextNode("RIGHT");
right.appendChild(t);
right.addEventListener("click", markCell)
document.body.appendChild(right);
```